# Cannot use MongoDB in an app deployed in Vercel

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nestjs, timeout, vercel

I have a NestJS application that I have just deployed using Vercel.
Using Node 16+, MongoDB 4.12.1, Mongoose 6.8.0

For some reason, all my requests are getting a timeout after 10 sec (which is the maximum for Vercel's free tier).
Following my investigation, I didn't got any timeout for endpoints that are not calling MongoDB, so I assume that this is the problem.
When I am running my application locally, it works like a charm, even using the vercel-admin-user credentials.

I have done the following for the integration:

1. Integrated MongoDB Atlas with Vercel following their guide: [link](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/products/atlas/how-to-connect-mongodb-atlas-to-vercel-using-the-new-integration/)
2. Created a vercel-admin-user with read and write access in MongoDB cluster
3. Allowed all network access to my cluster (0.0.0.0 & the exact Vercel IP address)

Comment: *Allowed all network access to my cluster*  it's OK of troubleshooting, but sake of all your users who suffer from data leaks, please don't do that on production. For the timeout, there is really not enough details to advise anything. You literally say "I did all right but it doesn't work". Evidently there is something wrong, and not necessarily with mongodb connction, as you imply. Please give us something to speculate on.

Comment: The reason you are getting a timeout is because mongodb is failing to connect. Check if your environment variables are correct. You'll have to click "redeploy" after changing env vars.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure:

- In environment-variables you have exactly `MONGODB_URI`.
- From your checkout page you're sending data to correct url (not with localhost).
- Add MongoDB at your Vercel account's integration section for your project.https://vercel.com/dashboard/integrations

Comment: this one really saved my day!

Comment: Please remember to remove MONGODB_URI from Vercel's environment variables before doing this, if not, MongoDB atlas fails without a warning.

Answer (score 1):

go to the mongodb account. then go to the database access. here you will see the new user called vercel-admin-user. then edit the user and set new password for it. then go to your project souce code change the mongodb pass & user in uri.